# Webpack - make redux-form external library

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have this kind of imports in my project:

```js
import {Field, reduxForm, FormSection, formValueSelector} from 'redux-form';
```

I want to make redux-form imports as an external library so that it won't be included into the build. As for example, it is done with Jquery:

```
externals: {
  jquery: 'jQuery'
}
```

So the question is more about how to make multiple imports from the same library as external without listing them explicitly in Webpack.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this to your webpack's config:

```
plugins: [
   // split vendor js into its own file
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks: function (module, count) {
        // any required modules inside node_modules are extracted to vendor
        return (
          module.resource &&
          /\.js$/.test(module.resource) &&
          module.resource.indexOf(
            path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')
          ) === 0
        )
      }
    }),
]
```

It will create new file called `vendor` include all your external library